# How to determine engine CG in order to calculate moments acting on it?

Tags: jet-engine, engine-design, multi-engine, cg

The aircraft has four engines mounted in pods under the wing. I know the values for the location of engine nacelle front face from the fuselage nose (longitudinal) and distance between engine centreline from fuselage centre line (lateral). I have also calculated the CG of the aircraft. The engine weight is 600kg, has nacelle diameter of 1.4m and the length of the pod is 3.5m. I do not know where and how the nacelle is attached to pylon. How do I estimate the value of Engine CG from the data provided?

Comment: Is this a homework question (which is out of scope and simple highschool math - but you also don't provide enough information to solve for the engine's CG location) or can this be answered by "ask the manufacturer" or "look at the datasheet"?

Comment: Yes this is for a homework but a long one (8 months). Since I do not have aerospace background, I am not too familiar with it. As for manufacturer, they don't have information or are not willing to share it with me. This is why I am asking for estimation or a way to assume some things. What other information do you need? If possible let me know what I should look into- any books or research papers to help me with it

Comment: Here’s one way to do it: start at the nose of the aircraft (or anywhere you like) and determine how far back each component is behind that.  Then consider the CoG which is some distance X behind the nose.  For each component you can form an expression of the form m*(d-X) where m us the mass of the component and d is the distance from the nose.  The whole expression gives the torque that the component exerts around the CoG.  If you add together the expressions for all of the components then the total should equal zero.

Comment: It’s easy then to find the value X that satisfies the equation and that’s the distance from the nose to the CoG.  You can repeat this using the vertical distance from some reference point if you want to know the vertical position of the CoG.  If your aircraft doesn’t have lateral symmetry you might need to do this a third time using spanwise offsets

Comment: @Frog Thank you! I found a CAD for it and became easier to find it by scaling it with known parameters

Comment: @itsChibi I’ll post it as an answer then, glad to be of help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s one way to do it: start at the nose of the aircraft (or anywhere you like) and determine how far back each component is behind that. Then consider the CoG which is some distance X behind the nose. For each component you can form an expression of the form m*(d-X) where m us the mass of the component and d is the distance from the nose. The whole expression gives the torque that the component exerts around the CoG. If you add together the expressions for all of the components then the total should equal zero.

It’s easy then to find the value X that satisfies the equation and that’s the distance from the nose to the CoG. You can repeat this using the vertical distance from some reference point if you want to know the vertical position of the CoG. If your aircraft doesn’t have lateral symmetry you might need to do this a third time using spanwise offsets.

Comment: Isn't this how to figure the aircraft CG?  I though the question was about the engine CG...

Comment: As worded it would apply to the entire aircraft but if one includes only the engine components then it will provide the CG of the engines.

Comment: I agree that if you know the aircraft CG both with and without the engine(s) you could determine the engine CG, but despite the math being simple I'm getting a little bogged down in your explanation... (I can be a bit thick sometimes!)  So, if you know the aircraft CG and datum, and you know the distance from the datum to the front face of the nacelle, how do you determine the arm of the engine?  (presuming the CG of the engine is not the front of the nacelle.)

Comment: It’s tricky because you don’t seem to have any information from which to calculate the engine’s CG.  For a piston engine you might guess that the CG will be a little forward of the midpoint of the nacelle, for a jet maybe a little further forward.  That’s speculation based on the heavy parts of both (propeller, compressor) being located at the front.

Comment: But wasn't that the question?  @itsChibi, are you asking about how to compute the engine's effect on the aircraft CG, or how to determine the CG of the engine itself so from that you know the arm, and can then compute aircraft CG?  (I presumed the latter based on the way it's worded.)